# Authentication with JWT: server or client-side?

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

I've been reading about how to set up JSON Web Tokens and all examples I found implement the authentication logic on the client side (e.g. [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack)).

As an example, imagine an app in which users can access a personal dashboard by just going to the root address. If not authenticated, the user should be redirected to a login or landing page. Following the best practices from the angular fullstack generator, the client would first download the whole Angular app, which would be then used to handle the authentication and routing, redirecting to the login page if necessary.

Assuming most visitors don't even have an account, why make them download all that code just to eventually show them a logging page?

Wouldn't it be better to simply serve a lightweight login page to non-authenticated users and the angular application only to users that already have a valid token?
If so, how come I don't find any examples implemented that way?

Answer (score 0):

You're facing one of the problems of token-based auth in frontend applications: At the initial request from the client to the server, the login-state is unknown to the server.

If your login form is *not* part of your Angular application, that's a common use case for cookie/session based auth, because cookies are delivered with the initial request. This way, the server knows whether to serve the angular application or to redirect to the login form.

But if your login form is part of your angular application, I don't see any problems in serving the whole application. After logging in (sending username + password to a server), you get a token which you use for all further request. In a classical single page application, this won't include any additional reloads.

Comment: But JWT can be stored as a cookie (as implemented in the example I gave above) and sent out in the first request, so the server should be able to tell whether that client is authenticated or not. In fact, I don't see how that is different from doing a full refresh once your app is loaded and auth'd. No need to rely on Angular to send that token. As for the practicality, assume you have significant amount of one-time visitors without account. Serving a thin landing page to those would make loading times faster and save bandwith. Or did I misunderstand something?